# My gulp plugin with through2 returns file in strange XML-like format

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, vinyl

I'm writing plugin for **Gulp**, and in order to process file i need to get it's full path. I used through2 package, then prepared `processFile(file)` function, but as an argument from through2 it receives file in strange XML-like format instead of object like `file.path`, `file.encoding` and so on.

How can I receive file.path when through2 is returning each file in following format:

`<File "relative/path/to/file/aaa.js" ...`

**Full code:**

```
var through = require('through2');

module.exports = function() {
  return through.obj(function(file, encoding, callback) {

    function processFile(file){
      console.log(file); // returns <File "relative/path/to/file/aaa.js" ...
    }

    callback(null, processFile(file));
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get on the console is just how `File` objects are turned into strings by `console.log`, which is what happens when you execute `console.log(file)`. Ultimately, the [`inspect` method](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/blob/3e8b132cd87bf5ab536ff7a4c6d660e33f5990b4/index.js#L123) is called and you get the results you see (which is not XML, by the way).

If I use your code and dump to the console `file.path`, I get the correct values. Same with `file.base` and `file.relative`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, since I have seen my console.log result I didn't try using file.path on it ;)